# "package io.grpc does not exist" and "static import only from classes and interfaces" when trying to generate Java Protobuf code

Tags: java, gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-java

I'm trying to follow along this blog post, https://redbyte.eu/en/blog/calling-java-from-go-using-grpc/, in this repository, https://github.com/khpeek/pdf-parser. After running `./gradlew build`, the project has the following structure:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── main
│   ├── extracted-include-protos
│   │   └── main
│   │       └── google
│   │           └── protobuf
│   │               ├── any.proto
│   │               ├── api.proto
│   │               ├── compiler
│   │               │   └── plugin.proto
│   │               ├── descriptor.proto
│   │               ├── duration.proto
│   │               ├── empty.proto
│   │               ├── field_mask.proto
│   │               ├── source_context.proto
│   │               ├── struct.proto
│   │               ├── timestamp.proto
│   │               ├── type.proto
│   │               └── wrappers.proto
│   ├── extracted-protos
│   │   └── main
│   ├── generated
│   │   ├── source
│   │   │   └── proto
│   │   │       └── main
│   │   │           ├── grpc
│   │   │           │   └── eu
│   │   │           │       └── redbyte
│   │   │           │           └── pdfparser
│   │   │           │               └── grpc
│   │   │           │                   └── PDFParserGrpc.java
│   │   │           └── java
│   │   │               └── eu
│   │   │                   └── redbyte
│   │   │                       └── pdfparser
│   │   │                           └── grpc
│   │   │                               ├── PDFParserApi.java
│   │   │                               ├── ParserRequest.java
│   │   │                               ├── ParserRequestOrBuilder.java
│   │   │                               ├── ParserResponse.java
│   │   │                               └── ParserResponseOrBuilder.java
│   │   └── sources
│   │       ├── annotationProcessor
│   │       │   └── java
│   │       │       └── main
│   │       └── headers
│   │           └── java
│   │               └── main
│   └── tmp
│       ├── compileJava
│       │   └── source-classes-mapping.txt
│       └── jar
│           └── MANIFEST.MF
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── src
    └── main
        └── proto
            └── pdfparserapi.proto

40 directories, 26 files
```

The issue is that `./gradlew build` returns the following errors:

```
> ./gradlew build

> Task :compileJava FAILED
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:3: error: package io.grpc does not exist
import static io.grpc.MethodDescriptor.generateFullMethodName;
                     ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:3: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.MethodDescriptor.generateFullMethodName;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:4: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncBidiStreamingCall;
                          ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:4: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncBidiStreamingCall;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:5: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncClientStreamingCall;
                          ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:5: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncClientStreamingCall;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:6: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncServerStreamingCall;
                          ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:6: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncServerStreamingCall;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:7: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncUnaryCall;
                          ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:7: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.asyncUnaryCall;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:8: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingServerStreamingCall;
                          ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:8: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingServerStreamingCall;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:9: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall;
                          ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:9: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:10: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.futureUnaryCall;
                          ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:10: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.futureUnaryCall;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:11: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.asyncBidiStreamingCall;
                          ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:11: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.asyncBidiStreamingCall;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:12: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.asyncClientStreamingCall;
                          ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:12: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.asyncClientStreamingCall;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:13: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.asyncServerStreamingCall;
                          ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:13: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.asyncServerStreamingCall;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:14: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.asyncUnaryCall;
                          ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:14: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.asyncUnaryCall;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:15: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.asyncUnimplementedStreamingCall;
                          ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:15: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.asyncUnimplementedStreamingCall;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:16: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
import static io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.asyncUnimplementedUnaryCall;
                          ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:16: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.asyncUnimplementedUnaryCall;
^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
@javax.annotation.Generated(
                 ^
  symbol:   class Generated
  location: package javax.annotation
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:30: error: package io.grpc does not exist
  private static volatile io.grpc.MethodDescriptor<eu.redbyte.pdfparser.grpc.ParserRequest,
                                 ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:38: error: package io.grpc does not exist
  public static io.grpc.MethodDescriptor<eu.redbyte.pdfparser.grpc.ParserRequest,
                       ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:65: error: package io.grpc does not exist
  public static PDFParserStub newStub(io.grpc.Channel channel) {
                                             ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:111: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
  public static final class PDFParserStub extends io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub<PDFParserStub> {
                                                              ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:73: error: package io.grpc does not exist
      io.grpc.Channel channel) {
             ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:138: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
  public static final class PDFParserBlockingStub extends io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub<PDFParserBlockingStub> {
                                                                      ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:81: error: package io.grpc does not exist
      io.grpc.Channel channel) {
             ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:164: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
  public static final class PDFParserFutureStub extends io.grpc.stub.AbstractStub<PDFParserFutureStub> {
                                                                    ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:263: error: package io.grpc does not exist
  private static volatile io.grpc.ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor;
                                 ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:265: error: package io.grpc does not exist
  public static io.grpc.ServiceDescriptor getServiceDescriptor() {
                       ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:165: error: package io.grpc does not exist
    private PDFParserFutureStub(io.grpc.Channel channel) {
                                       ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:169: error: package io.grpc does not exist
    private PDFParserFutureStub(io.grpc.Channel channel,
                                       ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:170: error: package io.grpc does not exist
        io.grpc.CallOptions callOptions) {
               ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:175: error: package io.grpc does not exist
    protected PDFParserFutureStub build(io.grpc.Channel channel,
                                               ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:176: error: package io.grpc does not exist
        io.grpc.CallOptions callOptions) {
               ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:139: error: package io.grpc does not exist
    private PDFParserBlockingStub(io.grpc.Channel channel) {
                                         ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:143: error: package io.grpc does not exist
    private PDFParserBlockingStub(io.grpc.Channel channel,
                                         ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:144: error: package io.grpc does not exist
        io.grpc.CallOptions callOptions) {
               ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:149: error: package io.grpc does not exist
    protected PDFParserBlockingStub build(io.grpc.Channel channel,
                                                 ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:150: error: package io.grpc does not exist
        io.grpc.CallOptions callOptions) {
               ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:112: error: package io.grpc does not exist
    private PDFParserStub(io.grpc.Channel channel) {
                                 ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:116: error: package io.grpc does not exist
    private PDFParserStub(io.grpc.Channel channel,
                                 ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:117: error: package io.grpc does not exist
        io.grpc.CallOptions callOptions) {
               ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:122: error: package io.grpc does not exist
    protected PDFParserStub build(io.grpc.Channel channel,
                                         ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:123: error: package io.grpc does not exist
        io.grpc.CallOptions callOptions) {
               ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:130: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
        io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver<eu.redbyte.pdfparser.grpc.ParserResponse> responseObserver) {
                    ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:87: error: package io.grpc does not exist
  public static abstract class PDFParserImplBase implements io.grpc.BindableService {
                                                                   ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:92: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
        io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver<eu.redbyte.pdfparser.grpc.ParserResponse> responseObserver) {
                    ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:96: error: package io.grpc does not exist
    @java.lang.Override public final io.grpc.ServerServiceDefinition bindService() {
                                            ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:192: error: package io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls does not exist
      io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.UnaryMethod<Req, Resp>,
                              ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:193: error: package io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls does not exist
      io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.ServerStreamingMethod<Req, Resp>,
                              ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:194: error: package io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls does not exist
      io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.ClientStreamingMethod<Req, Resp>,
                              ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:195: error: package io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls does not exist
      io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls.BidiStreamingMethod<Req, Resp> {
                              ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:206: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
    public void invoke(Req request, io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver<Resp> responseObserver) {
                                                ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:220: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
        io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver<Resp> responseObserver) {
                    ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:219: error: package io.grpc.stub does not exist
    public io.grpc.stub.StreamObserver<Req> invoke(
                       ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:229: error: package io.grpc.protobuf does not exist
      implements io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoFileDescriptorSupplier, io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoServiceDescriptorSupplier {
                                 ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:229: error: package io.grpc.protobuf does not exist
      implements io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoFileDescriptorSupplier, io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoServiceDescriptorSupplier {
                                                                               ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:250: error: package io.grpc.protobuf does not exist
      implements io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoMethodDescriptorSupplier {
                                 ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:33: error: package io.grpc.stub.annotations does not exist
  @io.grpc.stub.annotations.RpcMethod(
                           ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:37: error: package io.grpc.MethodDescriptor does not exist
      methodType = io.grpc.MethodDescriptor.MethodType.UNARY)
                                           ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:40: error: package io.grpc does not exist
    io.grpc.MethodDescriptor<eu.redbyte.pdfparser.grpc.ParserRequest, eu.redbyte.pdfparser.grpc.ParserResponse> getParseMethod;
           ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:46: error: package io.grpc.MethodDescriptor does not exist
              .setType(io.grpc.MethodDescriptor.MethodType.UNARY)
                                               ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:45: error: package io.grpc does not exist
              io.grpc.MethodDescriptor.<eu.redbyte.pdfparser.grpc.ParserRequest, eu.redbyte.pdfparser.grpc.ParserResponse>newBuilder()
                     ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
              .setFullMethodName(generateFullMethodName(
                                 ^
  symbol:   method generateFullMethodName(String,String)
  location: class PDFParserGrpc
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:50: error: package io.grpc.protobuf does not exist
              .setRequestMarshaller(io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils.marshaller(
                                                    ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:52: error: package io.grpc.protobuf does not exist
              .setResponseMarshaller(io.grpc.protobuf.ProtoUtils.marshaller(
                                                     ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:96: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @java.lang.Override public final io.grpc.ServerServiceDefinition bindService() {
    ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:97: error: package io.grpc does not exist
      return io.grpc.ServerServiceDefinition.builder(getServiceDescriptor())
                    ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:100: error: cannot find symbol
            asyncUnaryCall(
            ^
  symbol:   method asyncUnaryCall(MethodHandlers<ParserRequest,ParserResponse>)
  location: class PDFParserImplBase
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:121: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @java.lang.Override
    ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:132: error: cannot find symbol
          getChannel().newCall(getParseMethod(), getCallOptions()), request, responseObserver);
          ^
  symbol:   method getChannel()
  location: class PDFParserStub
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:132: error: cannot find symbol
          getChannel().newCall(getParseMethod(), getCallOptions()), request, responseObserver);
                                                 ^
  symbol:   method getCallOptions()
  location: class PDFParserStub
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:148: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @java.lang.Override
    ^
                           ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:217: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @java.lang.Override
    ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:232: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @java.lang.Override
    ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:237: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @java.lang.Override
    ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:257: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @java.lang.Override
    ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:266: error: package io.grpc does not exist
    io.grpc.ServiceDescriptor result = serviceDescriptor;
           ^
/Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/kurtpeek/pdf-parser/build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc/eu/redbyte/pdfparser/grpc/PDFParserGrpc.java:271: error: package io.grpc does not exist
          serviceDescriptor = result = io.grpc.ServiceDescriptor.newBuilder(SERVICE_NAME)
                                              ^
96 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 810ms
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

I've tried adding the following line to the `dependencies` in the `build.gradle`,

```
    compile group: 'io.grpc', name: 'protoc-gen-grpc-java', version: '1.14.0'
```

but this led to the same error. Any ideas how to fix the Gradle build?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`io.grpc.*` is in `grpc-api` (which most other grpc dependencies will depend on). `io.grpc.stub.*` is in `grpc-stub`. `io.grpc.protobuf.*` is in `grpc-protobuf`. `javax.annotation.Generated` can be found in Tomcat's `annotations-api`.

So you need to add (as mentioned in the [grpc-java readme](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/#download)):

```
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.14.0"
implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.14.0"
compileOnly "org.apache.tomcat:annotations-api:6.0.53"
```

gRPC v1.14.0 is quite old; you should upgrade to a newer version for actual use. To actually run, you probably need `implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.34.1'` as well.